# upload files using Url but not working

Tags: php, url, yii, yii2

guys, please help me in this problem which I have in yii2.
I start using AJAX uploads that work with Url

but when I Click upload file the error say '[image: Not Found (#404): Page not found.]'

FileInput tool from her

### http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/fileinput

cod in _form is:

```css
use yii\helpers\Url;


 <?= 
 FileInput::widget([
     'name' => 'attachment_48[]',
     'options'=>['multiple'=>true],
     'pluginOptions' => ['uploadUrl' => Url::to(['uploads/']),
         'uploadExtraData' => [
              'album_id' => 20,
              'cat_id' => 'Nature'
          ],
         'maxFileCount' => 10
     ]
 ]);?>
```

I think problem because Url and I 'use yii\helpers\Url;' but still not work

Comment: How you save the image in folder ??

Comment: no, I just wanna upload a pic to the folder using this tool (using Url::to) but dose not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Url::to()` method creates a URL based on the given parameters, not specify directory to upload. To handle it right, you should write your own action, which will handle your file uploading, and then point to it using this method:

```
Url::to(['mycontroller/myaction']);
```

Comment: Do you mean that I create an action to upload then call in my URL, and how please help I am new

Comment: Yes, you have to create your own action. Here's the guide: [Yii2 - uploading files](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html)